# Coincidence of notation in the classification of representations of affine Hecke algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, geometric-representation-theory, affine-hecke-algebras

This is spurred by a short discussion I had in the comments of [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212271/1-dimensional-representations-of-the-affine-hecke-algebra-for-sl-2?noredirect=1#comment1006738_212271).

In Ginzburg's 1998 paper, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9802004v3, or equivalently in the book by Chriss and Ginzburg, "Representation Theory and Complex Geometry", there is a classification of the irreducible representations of the affine Hecke algebra.
I'll be referring to definitions out of the book when possible.

Let $G = SL_n(\mathbb{C})$.
In the setup of Springer theory, $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the flag variety $G/B$, $\mathcal{N}$ denotes the nilpotent cone of $\mathfrak{g}$, and $\mathcal{B}_x$ denotes the Springer fibre (Borels fixed by $x \in \mathcal{N}$).
There is a canonical $G \times \mathbb{C}^*$-action on these varieties, and so for $a = (s,t) \in G \times \mathbb{C}^*$ a semisimple parameter, I can define equivariant versions
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{N}^a &= \{x \in \mathcal N : s\cdot x \cdot s^{-1} = t \cdot x\}, \\
\mathcal{B}^a &= \{\mathfrak{b} \in \mathcal B : s \cdot \mathfrak{b} \cdot s^{-1} \in \mathcal B \} \\
\mathcal{B}_x^s &= \{\mathfrak{b} \in \mathcal B : \mathfrak{b} \text{ simultaneously fixed by } s \text{ and } x \}.
\end{aligned}
Then $\mu$ denotes both the Springer resolution and the restriction to these fixed point varieties.

Let $G(s,x)$ denote the simultaneous centraliser of $s$ and $x$ in $G$, and let $C(s,x)$ denote the corresponding component group.
There is an action of $C(s,x)$ on the Borel-Moore homology $H_\bullet(\mathcal{B}_x^s)$ by convolution, and we can write down a $C(s,x)$-isotypic decomposition of this representation.

The 'standard modules' are defined to be $$K_{a,x,\chi} = \operatorname{Hom}_{C(s,x)}(\chi, H_\bullet(\mathcal B_x^s)),$$
where $\chi$ is an irreducible $C(s,x)$-module showing up in the above isotypic decomposition and $x$ is a $Z_G(s)$-orbit representative of $\mathbb{O}$ in $\mathcal{N}^a$.
For $S$ a local transverse slice to this orbit at $x$, I can write $\widetilde{S} = \mu^{-1}(S)$, so naturally $\mathcal{B}_x^s \hookrightarrow \widetilde{S}$.
This induces the pushforward in Borel-Moore homology,
$$ \psi: H_\bullet(\mathcal{B}_x^s) \to H_\bullet(\widetilde{S}). $$

**Now comes my confusion.**
The irreducible representations of the affine Hecke algebra associated to $G$ are denoted by $L_{a,x,\chi}$.
In the arXiv paper, these are explicitly the multiplicity spaces $L_\phi$, where $\phi = (\mathbb{O}, \chi)$ corresponds to an irreducible $G$-equivariant local system on $\mathbb{O}$ (this definition also shows up in the book of C and G).

On the other hand, the $L_{a,x,\chi}$ are also defined (on p. 416 of C and G) as $$ L_{a,x,\chi} := \operatorname{Hom}_{C(s,x)}(\chi, \operatorname{im} (\psi)), $$ where here (as previously) $\chi$ is an irreducible representation of $C(s,x)$.

Here is my question:

> The $L_{a,x,\chi}$ as they show up in the first definition are obtained via an equivariant version of decomposing certain perverse sheaves. The $L_{a,x,\chi}$ as they show up in the second definition are (much more easily) obtained via taking Borel-Moore homology of fibres over the nilpotent fixed point variety. **Why then do we use the first definition? Their equivalence is described somewhere in sections 8.5 and 8.6 of C and G, but is there something deeper/more general going on here that requires us to pass to the setting of equivariant perverse sheaves?**

Comment: Borel-Moore homology is just the cohomology of the dualizing complex, so you are in the setting of perverse sheaves from the start.